# Google workspace: file menu handling

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I have integrated Google Workspace into my web application. We are rendering it into our application using iframe.

Now the issue is that as per our web app requirements we want to disable certain options in menu like: File -> New,File -> Download, File -> Rename, File -> Print

I tried to do these changes using app scripts. I could do these using JS DOM model in front-end but is complex. I don't know if I am missing out on some solution I have no idea of. I have seen some websites implement this solution but I have no idea how I can do the same.

[check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e855G.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything. Apps Script and the Google APIs won't help since they don't provide a way to manipulate the built-in menu items. The different document-sharing options (viewer, commenter, editor) affect which menu items are disabled, but it doesn't align with what you want to achieve.

Is your document internally facing? Then you're left with DOM manipulation. Otherwise, [publish the sheet to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=1). All the UI elements, besides the table, are stripped away. But the data is publicly accessible.

Comment: Thank you Lewis Rodgers. I tried using DOM manipulation but I am unable to access elements first time without inspecting them atleast once in the browser Console.

Comment: Also I have below issues when handling DOM : 1) Ids are not constant for menu elements/tags 2) Using menu items parent element class getting undefined as response when accessing elements. We got struck here to go ahead with DOM manipulation because of these above two issues.

Comment: You mentioned that you've seen some websites implement the solution. Do you have actual examples of this?

Comment: Yeah, you can check on box.com . just signup with your email id, upload a google supported file and open it in respective editor of Google, there you can see it. somehow they were able to listen to click events of editor built in menu there.

Comment: Hi Lewis Rodgers. Any update on this will be greatly appreciated as we got stuck in fixing this